# Magento Shopping cart empty for cancelled payments

Tags: magento, instamojo

I'm using Instamojo in the payment section. For a cancel payment or a failure payment, the cart gets empty. How can it be overcome?

I want to save the cart item for unsuccessful payment attempts.

I used to replace this:

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
/**
* when there is redirect to third party, we don't want to save order yet.
* we will save the order in return action.
*/
if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
$result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
}
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

With this one:

```
 /**
* when there is redirect to third party, we don't want to save order yet.
* we will save the order in return action.
 */
if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
$result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->setIsActive(1) ;
}
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
 $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

in `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

but it's not working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?